# D3.js patterns for managing multiple elements bound to same data

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I'm learning D3 and my toy application is a visualizer for a 2-dimensional gravity simulation using [Symplectic Velocity Verlet Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration).

I have had quite some success animating and drawing a path using bound structured data, but it seems to me that D3 isn't really designed for attaching data to more than one element. It sort of assumes that for any given data that there is a clear and simple SVG element that should own it, and this is evident in the direct storage of data within the `__data__` property inside the DOM.

It's not clear, though, the proper way to represent a datum with more than one SVG element. For instance, I'd really prefer to draw a path *and* a circle for each planet, the path traces its past position (and can have a bunch of clever line-length and color interpolation applied), and the circle plots its current position.

I can even come up with a few more elements I might want to draw: A vector-arrow for velocity... A vector-arrow for acceleration...

In my case, my master data structure is constructed like this, and is dynamically maintained in this structure:

```
var data = [];
function makeParticle(x, y, vx, vy) {      
    // state vector plus goodies                 
    return [                               
        x, y,                              
        vx, vy,                            
        0, 0,                              
        [] // path                         
    ];                                     
}                                          
data.push(makeParticle(400, 100, -0.5, 1));
data.push(makeParticle(300, -100, 0.5, 2)); // and so on
```

Each element of data is a planet, which contains its current state vector (position, velocity, and cached acceleration (needed for the integrator)) as well as its path history which is an array of positions which is kept truncated to some reasonably large length.

Currently I am updating the path history like this:

```
var paths = d3.select('svg').selectAll("path").data(data);
paths.enter().append('path'); // put cool transitions here
paths.exit().remove();                                    

paths.attr("stroke", "red")                               
.attr("d", function(d){                                   
    return lineDrawer(d[6]);                              
})
```

This works fine, each path tracks its own copy of its own planet's path.

It's not immediately clear to me how to extend this elegantly to include my circle at the head of each path. I certainly do not want to duplicate the entire datum into the circle's DOM element (as the path data is simply not necessary for it).

**Edit** in light of my self-answer:

I am hoping that someone can help to elucidate a way to use "groups" to make data-driven the set of things to draw for each datum. e.g. `[position, velocity, force, path]` as data where they are visualized using, respectively, a circle, an arrow closed path, an arrow closed path, and an open path. It is also possible that this is completely overthinking it because these properties are sort of fixed.

Comment: The way to do this in general would be to have a `g` element with the data bound to it and then add everything based on that data underneath. If you use `.select()` to make a subselection, the data from the `g` element will be inherited automatically by the new child element as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the process of thinking the problem through, it's become clear to me that all I have to do is filter out the data, so that I only attach the position state data to `selectAll('circle.planet')` rather than the full datum value which includes the massive path history array. This way it gets exactly the data it is responsible for displaying.

It seems like I have to do some more reading about subselections (I'm mostly puzzled by why (or *if*) the subselections are limited to two dimensions of hierarchy), but this seems completely reasonable. It seems logical, if I want to draw 4 items for each datum, I just have to somehow "assign" the correct subsets of my datum's structure to each SVG visualizer element.